# Why do I get a 'FutureWarning' with pandas.concat?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, keyword-argument, future-warning

Does anyone meet this similar `FutureWarning`? I got this when I was using Tiingo+pandas_datareader?

The warning is like:

```
python3.8/site-packages/pandas_datareader/tiingo.py:234: FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas all arguments of concat except for the argument 'objs' will be keyword-only
    return pd.concat(dfs, self._concat_axis)
```

I think this warning does not impact my accessing to pandas data(in my case, I fetch from tiingo api), I can get all the data I want with no problem.
I just want to understand if there is any risk with my current enviroment:

```
my python3                -  3.8.5, 
Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
pandas_datareader version -  0.10.0
pandas version            -  1.3.2
```

I then tested my code with a 'futureVersion' of python: 3.9.6 (comparing with python 3.8.5). To my suprise, I no longer get any warning or error, everything works fine:

bellow are details updated

```
platform win32 
- Python 3.9.6, pytest-6.2.4, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Most function parameters in python are "positional or keyword" arguments.

I.e. if I have this function:

```
def do_something(x, y):
    pass
```

Then I can either call it like this, using positional arguments:

```
do_something(1, 2)
```

Or like this, using keyword arguments:

```
do_something(x=1, y=2)
```

Or like this, using a mixture of the two (but note that you're not allowed to have a positional argument after a keyword argument):

```
do_something(1, y=2)
```

### But you can also define functions with positional-only or keyword-only parameters

Say I have this other function:

```
def do_something_else(x, /, y, *, z):
    pass
```

In this function, I've marked `x` as being positional-only, because it comes before the `/`. And I've marked `z` as being keyword-only, because it comes after the `*`. `y` is a positional-or-keyword parameter, as it comes after the `/` but before the `*`. This means that these two attempts to call the function will fail: the first one because `z` is being called as a positional argument, and the second because `x` is being called as a keyword argument:

```
do_something_else(1, 2, 3)       # will fail!
do_something_else(x=1, y=2, z=3) # will fail!
```

These two attempts, however, will both succeed — `y` is still a positional-or-keyword parameter.

```
do_something_else(1, 2, z=3)     # fine
do_something_else(1, y=2, z=3)   # fine
```

### The `FutureWarning` message.

The `FutureWarning` message has nothing to do with the version of python you're using, but has everything to do with the version of `pandas` that you're using. `Pandas` is a third-party library, not a part of the python core, so the `pandas` version you're using is a completely different thing to the python version you're using.

The warning is letting you know that currently, you're fine to write `pd.concat(dfs, self._concat_axis)`, but that they're planning on changing the definition of the function in a future version of `pandas` so that all arguments except for `objs` will be keyword-only. I.e., after they make this change, `pd.concat(dfs, self._concat_axis)` will raise an error, and you will have to write `pd.concat(dfs, axis=self._concat_axis)` instead. They are most likely considering making this change because calling functions with keyword arguments is often clearer and more readable for other people.

Comment: hi Alex, this perfectly answer my question, appreciate!

Comment: Congrats, Alex! Could you also explain how to silence this warning?

Comment: @Ramon just use a keyword argument in your function call!